# IntentService not working in Android Lollipop when app close

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, intentservice

I make IntentService which the connect to web service every 15 minutes and show notification. When app was open, service work and notification was show, but when close app service work only in Android API < 21.

**IntentSerice:**

```
public class NotificationsService extends IntentService {

    private static final String TAG = "NotificationsService";

    public NotificationsService() {
        super(TAG);
    }

@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    ConnectionDetector checkNetwork = new ConnectionDetector(this);
    if (!checkNetwork.isNetworkAvailableAndConnected()) {
        return;
    }

    try {
        // Connect to web service
    } catch (IOException | JSONException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Error", e);
    }

    // Show notification
}

public static Intent newIntent(Context context) {
    return new Intent(context, NotificationsService.class);
}

public static void setNotificationServiceAlarm(Context context,
                                               boolean isNotificationEnable) {
    Intent intent = NotificationsService.newIntent(context);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(context, 0, intent,
                                                           PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    if (isNotificationEnable) {

        alarmManager.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP,
                                         SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + AlarmManager.INTERVAL_FIFTEEN_MINUTES,
                                         AlarmManager.INTERVAL_FIFTEEN_MINUTES,
                                         pendingIntent);
    } else {
        alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent);
        pendingIntent.cancel();
    }
}
```

**MainActivity:**

```
Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonStartService);
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        NotificationsService.setNotificationServiceAlarm(this, true);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In your case, is better to use Android notifications when your app is closed. In this way, is the system who notifies to your app that something new is available (you can add data to your notification). This is better, because if somebody install your app and every 15 minutes connects to your server, the result is an increase of downloaded data from your app and increase of battery use.
Read this post to more info: 
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html